# Vuejs 2 image slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flexslider, vuejs2

I have used flexslider in angularjs before. I am working on a laravel 5.3 project with vue.js 2. I have found a way to create a slider like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f7w6f4j/4/) but what I want is to have arrows on the images like how flexslider does it.

```
    new Vue({
    el: 'image-slider',
    data: {
        images: ['http://i.imgur.com/vYdoAKu.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/PUD9HQL.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/Lfv18Sb.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/tmVJtna.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/ZfFAkWZ.jpg'],
        currentNumber: 0,
        timer: null
    },

    ready: function () {
        this.startRotation();
    },

    methods: {
        startRotation: function() {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 3000);
        },

        stopRotation: function() {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
        },

        next: function() {
            this.currentNumber += 1
        },
        prev: function() {
            this.currentNumber -= 1
        }
    }
    });
```

Is there a package that does this or is there a way to modify the code to allow for that?

Comment: Do you mean displaying arrows like this theme? http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Yes, I actually want to make it work in a similar way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I used the Zurb Foundation orbit but I encountered issues when passing multiple images from the database. So I ended up using [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

I used `npm` to install then used `require`(webpack) like this:
`slick = require('slick-carousel');`

Then initialised it like this:

```
   updated: function () {
        $('.gallery').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            dots: false,
            arrows: true,
            responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 500,
                settings: {
                    dots: false,
                    arrows: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    slidesToShow: 1
                }
            }]
        });
```

Then I had to add the `scss` files when compiling my **SASS** files like this:

```
  mix.sass([
    'app.scss',
    '../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss',
    '../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss']);
```

And then just render the images using a `v-for` loop:

```
<section class='gallery' v-if="images">
    <div v-for="img in images">
        <img :src="img" class="image">
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using [carousel](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/) provided by [bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com) which is working fine for me.

You can see a demo of bootstrap carousel [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/hyxsusjf/) and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mimani/89421tbz/) with vue and vue-router.

I have also tried [jssor slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/) which was also quite easy to use and had option of [not using jquery](http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-no-jquery.html) as well.

**Code with bootstrap**

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.hallaminternet.com/assets/URL-tagging-image.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://www.shawacademy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/URL-1000x605.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://devcereal.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/URL-URI-URN-whats-difference.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

Zurb foundation also provides an image slider, which it calls orbit, documentation can be accessed [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/orbit.html).

Comment: I am using `Zurb Foundation`not `bootstrap`

Comment: @PhillisPeters foundation.zurb also provides [image slider](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/orbit.html), which can be used, I will add this in the answer.

Comment: I think there is an issue with using `.vue` component. For the last hour I have been trying to make the [orbit](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html) from foundation work with no success. Then I tried using the same on a `.blade.php ` file  and it works like a charm.

Comment: @PhillisPeters Can you create a js fidlle ot it and put it in the question.(ideally in new question as this is a separate issue)

Comment: I have asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179327/issue-with-foundation-used-in-vue-single-file-components)